# Does Apache Spark cache work on a derivative dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, caching

I'm doing some work using Apache Spark but I am not exactly sure whether the dataframe "frame3" will used cached data from "frame1" or not. Code describing the scenario conceptually below:

```
frame1 = spark.read.csv("hdfs:....")
frame1.cache()
frame2 = frame1.select("name", "price").filter("price > 20")
frame2.show() #Data is being cached so this action takes longer
frame2.show() #Data has been cached so this action takes a short amount of time
frame3 = frame2.select("name","price").filter("price > 30")
frame3.show() #Does this action use the cached data from frame 1 or not since frame 2 was built from frame 1?
```

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks,
Aurora

Answer (score 0):

in above scenario. DataFrame `frame3` will execute the `frame2` transformation. However, while doing this transformation, rather than reading a data from `csv` it will used the `cache` version of the dataframe `frame 1`

Spark uses lazy evolution to have better optimization. And so until you do any action none of the transformation is executed. This is good for the cases where you are doing multiple transformation on a single dataframe.

However, cases where a single transformed dataframe is being referenced into multiple other places, it's a good idea to cache that dataframe. Having said that. in above example I don't see `frame1` is being referenced anywhere else and so it won't make sense to even cache that. (unless if that's just an example to understand)

Note: updating answer as per comment, I missed our some important information. that until a proper action is performed on the dataframe it's not being cached.

Comment: in the above scenario, `frame1` will not be cached completely (`show` will not necessarily evaluate the entire data, especially because `frame2` is a narrow transfomrmation)